# Docker mount shows empty in wsl2

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu-18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I am using WSL2 with Docker Desktop 3.3.3 (Latest).
When I use docker containers inside a WSL2, I am not able to mount the required WSL2 files. Docker run will not give any issues, but it shows empty folder inside a container.

Any idea on this?

Comment: If you post your `docker run` command, we can see if there's some error in the use of the  volume parameter.

Comment: @rollingBalls here is the docker run command: docker run -it --rm --privileged -v /workspace:/ROOT_DIR/ myImage:1.0 bash

Comment: In `-v` the first path is the HOST one, the second is the CONTAINER one. If `/ROOT_DIR` is a path in your HOST, you want it like `-v /ROOT_DIR/:/workspace`.
If the order is what you meant, I'd check the dir path for typos.

Comment: Host and container directories are fine. I want to share the /workspace created in host to a container as /ROOT_DIR

Comment: When you say `/ROOT_DIR`, do you mean literally a path named `ROOT_DIR` or do you mean `/` (which is the root dir)?

Comment: literally a path named ROOT_DIR. It is just a name. You can consider different name aswell. It didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to mount a directory named "mydir", use the command:

```
docker run -it --name container_name -v /mydir:/mnt  image_name:version
```

Here, /mnt is the workspace inside the container where the files of "mydir" will be accessible.

Comment: am doing the same

Comment: Any error that you find or something else?

Comment: No errors. But no files are available in the mounted path if I open fro the container.

Comment: hi, where you able to fix this issue ?